# I want to return a specific row in MySQL whose column value is user input from a php form

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code I am using. It only returns queries whose value of `$isbn` **does not** start with 0.

The rows with isbn value like `:09913456` are not returned.

The same query in PhpMyadmin works fine.

```
$isbn = $_GET["isbn"];
$query = 'SELECT * FROM crossword_data WHERE isbn LIKE '.$isbn;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo $row['title'];
  }      

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to `SQL Injection` please consider using `PDO` for data access.

Comment: Please post your database structure.

Comment: What is the field type of the `isbn` field (varchar / number)?

Comment: I imagine it should be `varchar` or `char` due to the leading zeros.

Comment: `$isbn = "%;--"`. And now I have your entire table. Sanitize your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be aware of sql-injection: the user data goes right into your database! escape it. Otherwise everybody could slowdown, read, write or empty your data.

You treat your input like a number, but you mean a string. A number doesn't start with 0.

Solution would be

```
'SELECT * FROM crossword_data WHERE isbn LIKE "'.$isbn . '"'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM crossword_data WHERE isbn LIKE '.'%".$isbn."%';
```